# If IP is pingable then do something (convert bash command to dash)

Tags: bash, dash-shell

I have a command that should open a program after reboot if a specific IP is reachable. I use Debian so `sh` is linked to `dash`. The code that i execute after system start is:

```
sh -c "sleep 10 && if ping -c 1 stackoverflow.com &> /dev/null; then gedit; fi"
```

But with this code gedit will be opened in every case.

If i try in a bash console

```
sleep 10 && if ping -c 1 stackoverflow.com &> /dev/null; then gedit; fi
```

then it works correctly. So how can i convert the bash command correctly to dash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sh` doesn't have `&>`. You either need to use `bash -c ...` or redirect one descriptor at a time:

```
sh -c "sleep 1 && if ping -c 1 stackoverflow.com > /dev/null 2>&1; then notify-send hi; fi"
```